# Оператор & в функциях и const

Tags: ооп, c++

Немного подзабыл C++ , а может просто раньше и не сталкивался с этим, но на вид всё очень легко. Просто прошу напомнить следующее (можно в кратце, я всё понимаю, но вспомнить не могу, а гугл не воспринимает символ & в поисковой строке):

const после метода, насколько я знаю, означает защиту значений *this, а что значит const перед методом? Что значит оператор "&" в шаблонном типе? Это ведь оператор взятия адреса, здесь он причем? Правильно ли я понял, что "=0" в конце означает, что это pure метод? Если так, то зачем ему реализация в данном классе, если этот класс абстрактный, а сам метод будет переопределен в дочерних классах? Или я что-то путаю? Не люблю код, в котором опущены кавычки, вот и запутался...

Заранее спасибо! Вот, кстати, и сам код :)

```
template < class UnknownType > class MyClass
{
public:
    virtual const UnknownType& method() const throw () = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. всё просто UnknownType& это тип:
       **ссылка на UnknownType**
2. а const для того чтобы нельзя было
       изменить то что возвращается
3. да это pure метод, вот только вы не
       показали что там есть реализация

Comment: 1 и 2 понял, спасибо. А вот насчет 3: разве вызов исключения в данном случае не будет реализацией?

Comment: 'throw' здесь не реализация, а описание того, какие могут бросаться исключения. В данном случае 'throw ()' указывает что никакие исключения из этой функции бросаться не могут.

Comment: Как это правильно называется, что бы можно было погуглить? В статьях про "try catch throw" никогда этого не видел...

Comment: это называется [exception specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec). Пункт 15.4 стандарта.

Comment: Почитал, разобрался.
Но теперь опять возник вопрос по первому пункту - как будет выглядеть вызов такого метода? const int object = method(); И теперь object будет ссылкой? Const в данном случае писать обязательно?

Comment: Надо int&, а не просто int. Const обязателен. http://ideone.com/zPyGXQ

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень наглядный пример